# Phone number stolen. What to do?

Tags: phone, sms

It seems a friend of mine got his phone number stolen. Someone got access to his Facebook account (where they tried to post ad campaigns) and to his WhatsApp account. The Facebook security page said his account was accessed using his password and phone validation. This combined with the WhatsApp access is what makes us think they have access to his text messages.

He does not have a smartphone, and he recently got a new phone from a little-known brand (a "Danew konnect 245 Bara", this phone: https://danew.fr/product/bara-blue/), and he recently spent some time at airports. He says he received an SMS a while back saying asking him to confirm a new login, but he deleted the message. It was around the time of buying the new phone, but he's not sure if it was just before or just after.

I've read about people transferring your number to other providers to take over access to your phone, but he can still make and receive calls using his phone number. He called his provider and they said he hasn't requested any new sim card lately, and they couldn't see any other suspicious activity. His phone (both the old and the new) does not support apps, so he hasn't installed anything himself. I've never heard of copying sim cards through wireless means. Could it be that the new phone is somehow malicious or had a security flaw that allowed this to happen? He bought a new phone now just in case.

To me it sounds impossible that the phone number was stolen considering he can still access it, but I don't know what else to make of these facts. Could these things have been accessed some other way? And more importantly, what can he do to secure himself now?

Comment: Rather than the phone number being "stolen," it sounds like he has a compromised phone. Did he ever log in to Facebook on the phone?

Comment: He did not, the phone has no such features.

Comment: Could it be that the phone somehow copied his SIM card or passed on his messages?

Comment: SMS interception is relatively easy. Don't count on phone 2FA too much.

Comment: Ok! Other than not counting on phone 2FA, are there any steps he can take to protect himself from ongoing attacks from this attacker?

Comment: Does he have an eSIM, maybe? But the provider should know.

Comment: @Overmind: But that relies on having another SIM,

Comment: @Anton: Get a different phone number from the provider.

Comment: He does not have an eSIM. The attacker just tried to access his Gmail account as well (he got a Google code SMS). We changed his number to another one he has. What I'm getting from your messages is that there's no way to regain control of this phone number, so it should be thrown away. Is that the only possible solution?